# how to Divide class based frames in tkinter frames into different python files

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter application which is divide into many classes(frames in tkinter) the program has become 1000+ lines and now I want to divide it into deferent files can any one guide me how can I achieve this.

my code is like

```
class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):  #this is the class which make navigation pages possible 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.frames = {}
        self.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

        for F in (StartPage, connect_page, login_page, signup_page, dashboard_page,trip_page,destination_reached_page):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        #some code .....

class connect_page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        #some page...

#more classes like this ........
```

I want to divide the pages into different python files and and main class `tkinterApp`
in different file is this possible if How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cut / paste the class and all the imports it needs into another file, then import it.

```
# start_page.py

import tkinter as tk

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        #some code .....
```

and then in your main file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# main_program.py

from start_page import StartPage

# rest of your code
```

As a side note, 1000+ lines is not that large and not uncommon. You may want to read up on your IDE's code navigation features.